# Auto Power ON and Accessing BIOS then immediately shutting down

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, shutdown

As we all know, BIOS is normally (if not always-- depending on the answer to this question) opened immediately after booting/powering on the computer.

Well in the case that my computer is already on and I need to access the BIOS why isn't there an option like to access the BIOS and then shutdown or restart into BIOS mode ( the same way you can reboot into safe mode without picking it at startup) this is much more convenient.

Or a more rational question would be why can't I set something in the BIOS and then save and shutdown. After doing anything in BIOS the computer has to always boot is there any way around this?

---

The reason I want this is because I like the BIOS Auto Power On feature. However it lacks features e.g you have to set the pc to power up every day at the same time OR one day at a specific time. But you cant set a time for each day of the week. So maybe this would be a different way of solving my problem.

Comment: If you want an answer to "why", then it's quite simple; design and hardware limitations.

Comment: Both why and a work around also would be ideal.

Comment: Different hardware designers put in different features to different motherboards.  I've only ever seen per-weekday BIOS boot scheduling on one model of HP, although I admit it's not something I looked for.  In other words, only desktop hardware that specifically designed to do it would do it.

Comment: Server motherboards are frequently designed with remote management and capabilities like you're talking about, built into ILO or iDRAC.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to use Wake-on-LAN to schedule boot times for your computer? I've never tried it, just a thought...

Comment: Wake on LAN requires the computer to be on sleep mode I think either that *or* it required port forwarding which is quite long i think.